# Why I cannot display less than 6 days?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to display some data using HighStock. Everything works quite fine beside the fact that I cannot display less than 6 days.
As you can see below, I have selected 3 days as range but the chart still shows 6 columns.
Moreover, if I try to select any day after April 18 as "from" value, the value is ignored and April 18, 2013 is considered. Finally, I have the same behavior if I try to pinch the navigator, I cannot display less than 6 days.

I have looked into HighStock API Reference but I cannot find any reference to the fact that 6 is de default number of days/values shown.

[image]

Below I report my js:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
        backgroundColor: '#E5E7EB'
    },
      rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            type: 'day',
            count: 3,
          text: '3d'
        }, {
            type: 'week',
            count: 1,
            text: '1w'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
            count: 1,
            text: '1m'
        }, {
            type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'ytd',
            count: 1,
                text: 'Ytd'
        },{
                type: 'year',
            count: 1,
                text: '1y'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
            text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 1
      },

      xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // daily
    },

    yAxis: {
        offset: 8,
        title: {
            text: yAxisTitle
        },
        labels: {
        align:'right'
    }
    },

      plotOptions: {
            column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
      }
    }
      },
      series: seriesOptions
    });
```

Am I missing anything? How may I display less than 6 days/values?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set minRange http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange

In your example: 3 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 (which means 3 days)

Comment: Thanks for you help. minRange solved the issue.

Do you know how I can display yesterday as the latest day on the xAxis (instead today)? In my app the latest available data is the one registered the day before the current one and right now I have as latest column an empty one that I wish not to display. THANKS.

Comment: You can use setExtremes() function to define your own range. Then only what you need is set first / last "range egdes". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260053/highchart-with-scaled-images-in-column-bars