# Need to skew images(increase height and maintain the base width of pyramid) instead of bars

Tags: css, svg, highcharts, transform, skew

[image]

I am using highcharts library to create charts.

I want to know if I can use an svg image instead of a bars.
I am attaching the image of how it should look like.
The base width should be the same, but the height must vary.

I do not want to fill the bar like it is suggested here:
[use image to fill bars in highchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841120/use-image-to-fill-bars-in-highchart)

I do not want to create just a triangle bar chart like here:
http://jsfiddle.net/83jXA/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            inverted: true
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Expenditure Chart'
        },
        tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                if (this.x > 0) {
                    return 'USD '+this.y +' million';
                } else { return false; }
            }

        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                '',
                '2010',
                '',
                '',
                '',
                '2011',
                ''],
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickWidth: 0

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            gridLineColor: '#ffffff',
            min: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            area: {
                fillOpacity: 0.5,

            },


        },
        series: [{
            name: '2010',
            data: [0, 3, 0, null, null, null, null],
            marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
            }

        }, {
            name: '2011',
            data: [null, null, null, null, 0, 6, 0],
                        marker: {
                    symbol: 'circle'
            }


        }],

    });
});
```

I just need to replace bar with svg image and adjust height.
The base width should be the same, but the height must vary.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260053/highchart-with-scaled-images-in-column-bars/16300743#16300743

Is this what you want?

Comment: @KacperMadej That fiddle is not working.

Comment: Try with this one - http://jsfiddle.net/YZkPX/45/

Comment: @KacperMadej  You made my day. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!